# Parse time string using regex

Tags: regex

My time string may be in one of the following formates (`x` and `y` - *integer* numbers, **h** and **m** - symbols):

- `x`h `y`m
- `x`h
- `y`m
- `y`

Examples:

- 1h 20m
- 45m
- 2h
- 120

What regular expression should I write to get `x` and `y` numbers from such string?

Comment: what kind of regex? Is it in a C/C++ api, perl or something different. What will you do with the values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're using .NET due to your username. :)

I think in this case, it's easier to use [`TimeSpan.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988456.aspx) for this task.

You can specify a list of permitted formats ([see here for the format for these](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx)) and `ParseExact` will read in the `TimeSpan` according to them.

Here is an example:

```
var formats = new[]{"h'h'", "h'h 'm'm'", "m'm'", "%m"};
    // I have assumed that a single number means minutes

foreach (var item in new[]{"23","1h 45m","1h","45m"})
{   
    TimeSpan timespan;
    if (TimeSpan.TryParseExact(item, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out timespan))
    {
        // valid
        Console.WriteLine(timespan);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
00:23:00
01:45:00
01:00:00
00:45:00
```

The only problem with this is that it is rather inflexible. Additional whitespace in the middle will fail to validate. A more robust solution using Regex is:

```
var items = new[]{"23","1h 45m", "45m", "1h", "1h 45", "1h   45", "1h45m"};
foreach (var item in items)
{
    var match = Regex.Match(item, @"^(?=\d)((?<hours>\d+)h)?\s*((?<minutes>\d+)m?)?$", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
    if (match.Success)
    {       
        int hours;
        int.TryParse(match.Groups["hours"].Value, out hours); // hours == 0 on failure

        int minutes;
        int.TryParse(match.Groups["minutes"].Value, out minutes);

        Console.WriteLine(new TimeSpan(0, hours, minutes, 0));
    }
}
```

Breakdown of the regex:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=\d)` - must start with a digit (do this because both parts are marked optional, but we want to make sure at least one is present)
- `((?<hours>\d+)h)?` - hours (optional, capture into named group)
- `\s*` - whitespace (optional)
- `((?<minutes>\d+)m?)?` - minutes (optional, capture into named group, the 'm' is optional too)
- `$` - end of string

Answer (score 4):

```
(\d+)([mh]?)(?:\s+(\d+)m)?
```

You can then inspect groups 1-3. For your examples those would be

```
('1', 'h', '20')
('45', 'm', '')
('2', 'h', '')
('120', '', '')
```

As always, you might want to use some anchors `^`, `$`, `\b`...

Comment: Good answer. It can match 5 7m or 5m 7m but if the input set is well defined as given by the OP, it isn't a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that mhyfritz' solution is simple, efficient and good if your input is only what you shown.
If you ever need to handle corner cases, you can use a more discriminative expression:

```
^(\d+)(?:(h)(?:\s+(\d+)(m))?|(m?))$
```

But it can be overkill...

(get rid of ^ and $ if you need to detect such pattern in a larger body of text, of course).

Answer (score 1):

Try this one: `^(?:(\d+)h\s*)?(?:(\d+)m?)?$`:

```
var s = new[] { "1h 20m", "45m", "2h", "120", "1m 20m" };

foreach (var ss in s)
{
    var m = Regex.Match(ss, @"^(?:(\d+)h\s*)?(?:(\d+)m?)?$");

    int hour = m.Groups[1].Value == "" ? 0 : int.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value);
    int min = m.Groups[2].Value == "" ? 0 : int.Parse(m.Groups[2].Value);

    if (hour != 0 || min != 0)
        Console.WriteLine("Hours: " + hour + ", Mins: " + min);
    else
        Console.WriteLine("No match!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in bash

```
echo $string | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i}' | sed s/[hm]/""/g
```